# change color of bar for data selection in seaborn histogram (or plt)

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, distribution

Let's say I have a dataframe like:

```
X2 = np.random.normal(10, 3, 200)
X3 = np.random.normal(34, 2, 200)

a = pd.DataFrame({"X3": X3, "X2":X2})
```

and I am doing the following plotting routine:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2,  gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":(.10, .30)}, figsize = (13, 4))
for i, c in enumerate(a.columns):
    sns.boxplot(a[c], ax=axes[0,i])
    sns.distplot(a[c], ax = axes[1,i])
    axes[1, i].set(yticklabels=[])
    axes[1, i].set(xlabel='')
    axes[1, i].set(ylabel='')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Which yields to:

[image]

Now I want to be able to perform a data selection on the dataframe a. Let's say something like:

```
b = a[(a['X2'] <4)]
```

and highlight the selection from b in the posted histograms.
for example if the first row of b is [32:0] for X3 and [0:5] for X2, the desired output would be:

[image]

is it possible to do this with the above for loop and with sns? Many thanks!

EDIT: I am also happy with a matplotlib solution, if easier.

EDIT2:

If it helps, it would be similar to do the following:

```
b = a[(a['X3'] >38)]

f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2,  gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":(.10, .30)}, figsize = (13, 4))

for i, c in enumerate(a.columns):
   sns.boxplot(a[c], ax=axes[0,i])
   sns.distplot(a[c], ax = axes[1,i])
   sns.distplot(b[c], ax = axes[1,i])

   axes[1, i].set(yticklabels=[])
   axes[1, i].set(xlabel='')
   axes[1, i].set(ylabel='')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which yields the following:

[image]

**However, I would like to be able to just colour those bars in the first plot in a different colour!**
I also thought about setting the ylim to only the size of the blue plot so that the orange won't distort the shape of the blue distribution, but it wouldn't still be feasible, as in reality I have about 10 histograms to show, and setting ylim would be pretty much the same as sharey=True, which Im trying to avoid, so that I'm able to show the true shape of the distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the solution for this using the inspiration from the previous answer and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmjMQkUych8&ab_channel=Amulya%27sAcademy) video:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2021)
X2 = np.random.normal(10, 3, 200)
X3 = np.random.normal(34, 2, 200)

a = pd.DataFrame({"X3": X3, "X2":X2})
b = a[(a['X3'] < 30)]


hist_idx=[]

for i, c in enumerate(a.columns):
    bin_ = np.histogram(a[c], bins=20)[1]
    hist = np.where(np.logical_and(bin_<=max(b[c]), bin_>min(b[c])))
    hist_idx.append(hist)
    

f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2,  gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":(.10, .30)}, figsize = (13, 4))

for i, c in enumerate(a.columns):
    sns.boxplot(a[c], ax=axes[0,i])
    axes[1, i].hist(a[c], bins = 20)
    axes[1, i].set(yticklabels=[])
    axes[1, i].set(xlabel='')
    axes[1, i].set(ylabel='')
    
for it, index in enumerate(hist_idx):
    lenght = len(index[0])
    for r in range(lenght):
        try:
            axes[1, it].patches[index[0][r]-1].set_fc("red")
        except:
            pass 


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which yields the following for `b = a[(a['X3'] < 30)]` :

[image]

or for `b = a[(a['X3'] > 36)]`:
[image]

Thought I'd leave it here - although niche, might help someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

I created the following code with the understanding that the intent of your question is to add a different color to the histogram based on the data extracted under certain conditions.
Use `np.histogram()` to get an array of frequencies and an array of bins. Get the index of the value closest to the value of the first row of data extracted for a certain condition. Change the color of the histogram with that retrieved index. The same method can be used to deal with the other graph.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2021)
X2 = np.random.normal(10, 3, 200)
X3 = np.random.normal(34, 2, 200)

a = pd.DataFrame({"X3": X3, "X2":X2})

f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2,  gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":(.10, .30)}, figsize = (13, 4))
for i, c in enumerate(a.columns):
    sns.boxplot(a[c], ax=axes[0,i])
    sns.distplot(a[c], ax = axes[1,i])
    axes[1, i].set(yticklabels=[])
    axes[1, i].set(xlabel='')
    axes[1, i].set(ylabel='')

b = a[(a['X2'] <4)]
hist3, bins3 = np.histogram(X3)
idx = np.abs(np.asarray(hist3) - b['X3'].head(1).values[0]).argmin()

for k in range(idx):
    axes[1,0].get_children()[k].set_color("red")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this is very close to it, thanks for that! However, I want to plot all indexes on the b dataframe, not only the first one. I've been trying to change the way you come up with the ```idx``` but can't figure it out @r-beginners

Comment: If it helps, what I want to show is that one sample that contains a lot of variable "X3" might not contain a lot of "X2". In other words, I want to show, for example, the bins where X3 >10 , where are they located in X2 - I'm guessing it is still with the ```idx``` just a different way to subset.

Comment: If the starting value is from 0, we can deal with it up to the index value we found in the loop.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work. If I do the selection ```b = a[(a['X3']>38)]``` , the final plot does not show the bins that are more than 38 units of X3.

Comment: I think what is happening is that the Y-axis of the new graph is so large that we can no longer see more than 38. The frequency values in `b = a[(a['X3'] > 38)]` are the following.`hist3;array([ 3,  2, 17, 26, 45, 48, 27, 22,  7,  3], dtype=int64)`

Comment: As a way to verify, try increasing the height of the second graph or increasing the height of the graph size.