# Problem with creating bar plots for KMeans-based clustering algorithm

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm struggling to plot bar charts for the KMeans-based clustering algorithm. The problem is I want to demonstrate clusters in such a way that the very outlier cluster can be depicted at the end of the x-axis & the rest of the clusters stay relatively next to each other. I think the problem is `xsticks`, which are equally distributed on the x-axis:

```
---|---|---|-----------------> x-axis
0  1   2   3
```

in this context, I want to show that, e.g. cluster predicted with labelled `3` based on `Score` located a bit far which needs some adjustment concerning bins width maybe like this:

```
---|---|--------------|------> x-axis
0  1   2              3
```

So far I reached the following results to demonstrate results of the KM-based algorithm concerning outlier detection:
[image: img]

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
from math import pow
import math

class ODKM:
    
    def __init__(self,n_clusters=15,effectiveness=500,max_iter=2):
        self.n_clusters=n_clusters
        self.effectiveness=effectiveness
        self.max_iter=max_iter
        self.kmeans = {}
        self.cluster_score = {}
        #self.labels = {}
        
    def fit(self, data):
        length = len(data)
        for column in data.columns:
            kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=self.n_clusters,max_iter=self.max_iter)
            self.kmeans[column]=kmeans
            kmeans.fit(data[column].values.reshape(-1,1))
            assign = DataFrame(kmeans.predict(data[column].values.reshape(-1,1)),columns=['cluster'])
            cluster_score=assign.groupby('cluster').apply(len).apply(lambda x:x/length)
            ratio=cluster_score.copy()
        
            sorted_centers = sorted(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
            max_distance = ( sorted_centers[-1] - sorted_centers[0] )[ 0 ]
        
            for i in range(self.n_clusters):
                for k in range(self.n_clusters):
                    if i != k:
                        dist = abs(kmeans.cluster_centers_[i] - kmeans.cluster_centers_[k])/max_distance
                        effect = ratio[k]*(1/pow(self.effectiveness,dist))
                        cluster_score[i] = cluster_score[i]+effect
                        
            self.cluster_score[column] = cluster_score
                    
    def predict(self, data):
        length = len(data)
        score_array = np.zeros(length)
        for column in data.columns:
            kmeans = self.kmeans[ column ]
            cluster_score = self.cluster_score[ column ]
            #labels = kmeans.labels_ 
            assign = kmeans.predict( data[ column ].values.reshape(-1,1) )
            #print(assign)
            
            for i in range(length):
                score_array[i] = score_array[i] + math.log10( cluster_score[assign[i]] )
            
        return score_array #,labels
    
    def fit_predict(self,data):
        self.fit(data)
        return self.predict(data)
```

test the results:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'attr1':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,15],
                        'attr2':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,13,13,13,14,15]})

#generate score from KM-based algorithm via class ODKM
odkm_model = ODKM(n_clusters=3, max_iter=1)
result = odkm_model.fit_predict(df)

#include generated scores to the main frame to reach desired plot
df['ODKM_Score']= result 
df

#for i in result:
#    print(round(i,2))

#results
#-0.51, -0.51 , -0.51 , -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51
#-0.78, -0.78, -0.78, -0.78, -0.78, -0.78, -0.78
#-0.99, -0.99, -0.99, -0.99
#-1.99
```

You can find my entire code, including this KM-based algorithm, in [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Lzzsk8ZTkOajGksJIgCPeAeEWjGTgFAd?usp=sharing) for quick debugging. Please feel free to implement your solutions on notebook or comment on cells if you need it, or some changes within the `ODKM` algorithm itself (where KM clustering executing) has been scripted can access in the form of `@class ODKM`. Maybe it is better to extract predicted cluster labels and add a new column under the title of `Cluster_label` next to the `ODKM` algorithm `Score` for better access to the bar plots.

The expected output should be like this(better bins within the same clusters have the same color, e. g. 1st cluster `C1`):

[image: img]

**Update**: Apart from the bar plot solution, I can plot Hist & distribution but I can't figure out how to colour up and pass cluster labels to reflect clustering results on bins within histogram as expected.

```py
##left output
# just plot 'Score' column (not all columsn in 1st phase) to simply the problem
#cols_ = df.columns[-1:] 
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))
df['Score'].plot(kind='hist', ax=ax1 , color='b', alpha=0.4)
df['Score'].plot(kind='kde', ax=ax1, secondary_y=True, label='distribution', color='b', lw=2)

##Right output
sns.distplot(df['Score'] , color='b')
```

Despite reflecting results of clustering on the graph, I noticed that there are some differences, as I highlighted in the below picture between these two plots e. g. the scale of the y-axis & gap issue between main bins close to the origin of the x-axis:

[image: img]

I also found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66325301/change-color-of-bar-for-data-selection-in-seaborn-histogram-or-plt), but I couldn't adapt to `@class ODKM` to resolve my problem dynamically.
I could also achieve this recently:

```py
df['Score'] = df['Score'].abs()
sns.displot(df, 
            x='Score',
            hue='Cluster_labels',
            palette=["#00f0f0","#ff0000","#00ff00"],
             alpha=1)
```

[image: img]

Comment: Do you want to assign cluster labels based on just the score values, or do you want to also include the other columns?

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with KMeans or clustering? I'd recommend simplifying the question you have about plotting.

Comment: @warped Right, for all columns exclusively on the `Score` column. but before this, we need to return predicted labels inside of `@class ODKM:` by using the attribute `.labels_ ` as in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

Comment: @mwaskom I referring KM clustering method if there was a chance to reach desired output with *bar plot* by using clustering calculation e. g, ticks manipulating over x-axis to highlight [out cluster(s)](https://i.imgur.com/rrwzsMa.png).

Answer (score 0):

For the 1D case, you can use the centers of the clusters as the x-positions for your bars.

```
n_clusters=3

km = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=n_clusters).fit(df[['Score']])

counts = np.bincount(km.labels_)

for center, count, label in zip(km.cluster_centers_, counts, range(n_clusters)):
    print(center, count)
    plt.bar(center, count, width=0.2, label=label)
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I edited your answer slightly and include a legend but I tried to change `color` argumenet unsuccessfully to highlight the *outlier cluster bar*. 2nd problem is wherein `@class ODKM` I can retrieve clustering info `center`, `count`, `label`? Did you check 1st cell of [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Lzzsk8ZTkOajGksJIgCPeAeEWjGTgFAd?usp=sharing)?

Comment: I did not look at your colab notebook. Please edit your question such that it reproduces your issue and contains the parts that are relevant, and please refrain from linking to external content.

Comment: I edited so that you can check it and retrieve KM info within `class ODKM` and return it if was possible and hopefully plot the results of `class ODKM` which is so-called `'ODKM_Score'` from `result`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'attr1':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,15],
                        'attr2':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,13,13,13,14,15]
                        })

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

def kmeans_scatterplot(df):

    column_i = 'attr1'
    column_j = 'attr2'

    df_temp = df[[column_i, column_j]]
    
    # model
    y_pred = DBSCAN(eps = 3, min_samples = 1).fit_predict(df_temp)
    
    # plot
    plt.scatter(df_temp[column_i], df_temp[column_j], c=y_pred, cmap='rainbow', alpha=0.7, edgecolors='b')

    plt.show()
kmeans_scatterplot(df)
```

This clustering only needs to specify the distance, and then we can label the color according to the category.

It will help you quickly understand the principle of this algorithm: https://www.naftaliharris.com/blog/visualizing-dbscan-clustering/

Comment: I see your point of view but `class ODKM` is KMeas based. The idea is to reflect the results of KMeans clustering within `class ODKM` on `ODKM_Score` Histot-distribution (like bar charts e. g. `displot` or `distplot`). Please see your solution [output](https://i.imgur.com/gv5Prmc.png) compare to the distribution of `ODKM_Score`. At first I thought that you offer to use DBSCAN method for visualizing  & reflecting the results of class ODKM on `ODKM_Score` but the question is how can collect KMeans clustering info *within*  `class ODKM`  to reflect on `class ODKM` output which is `ODKM_Score`.